# How to calculate the day of the week from a specific date using Html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do i arrive on a specific day of the week in javascript given the HTML inputs. please help out.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: What HTML inputs? Please provide more information such as possible input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input provides the date as javascript date object. Then you can do -

```
var dayOfTheWeek=jsDateObj.getDay()
```

[getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week as a number mapped as below -

> Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6

You can map this number to the day in string if you want it in string format. This is easy to do as shown below -

```
const daysOfTheWeekArray = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var dayOfTheWeek=jsDateObj.getDay()
console.log(daysOfTheWeekArray[dayOfTheWeek])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] =  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```